# setTimeout firing function straight away and not waiting

Tags: javascript

Rather than waiting 5 seconds my use of setTimeout seems to be executing straight away:

```
window.setTimout(getNegativeErrs(errors), 5000);

  function getNegativeErrs(ers) {
    for( i in errors ) {
      var errobj = getByValue(dataLayer, errors[i]);
      if(!errobj) {
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'negative_errors',
          'unseen': errors[i],
          'module': 'registration'
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Must the function being passed be of a specific format? I really don't know what to edit here or where to start looking?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Write a function expression as first argument inside of which you call your target function (with its arguments). `setTimeout(function(){foo(bar)}, 5000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `getNegativeErrs()` is executing right away and is using its return value as the callback.

The right way:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    getNegativeErrs(errors)
    }, 5000);

  function getNegativeErrs(ers) {
    for( i in errors ) {
      var errobj = getByValue(dataLayer, errors[i]);
      if(!errobj) {
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'negative_errors',
          'unseen': errors[i],
          'module': 'registration'
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I'm getting an error window.setTimout is not a function?

Comment: Check for any mis-spellings or just try it as `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Yes, was a typo fixed now thank you very much

Comment: Alrighty then. Good coding!

Comment: Just a fly follow up, presumably the same applies to setInterval as well as setTimeout?

Comment: As regards to the callback? Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval